# Python remove hashtag symbol and keep key words

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I want to remove hashtag symbol (`'#'`) and underscore that separate between words (`'_'`)

Example: `"this tweet is example #key1_key2_key3"`

the result I want: `"this tweet is example key1 key2 key3"`

My code  using string :

```
#Remove punctuation , # Hashtag Symbol 
translate_table = dict((ord(char), None) for char in string.punctuation)   
cleaned_combined_tweets.translate(translate_table)
```

which gives the result: `"this tweet is example key1key2key3"`

Comment: What is wrong with the [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> "this tweet is example #key1_key2_key3".replace("#", "").replace("_", " ")
```

Answer (score 1):

first strip all hash tags as they are at the start, then replace all underscores with spaces; simple and easy solution.

revised code:

```
string = "This tweet is example #key1_key2_key3"
string = string.strip("#")
string = string.replace("_"," ")
print(string)
```

Comment: I think `str.strip` only works on the ends of a string.

Comment: And to be honest it is a shorter way than using replace when you just wanna get rid of it, so that's why I used it not replace twice.

Comment: 'Return a copy of the string with leading or trailing characters removed'-I think you are wrong actually

Comment: `strip` only removes from start and end, try yourself `s = "abc#def"; s.strip("#"); 'abc#def'`

Comment: This time, no my friend.  Read through your post and the comments.  Run your code in a fresh prompt.  See the output and think again.

Comment: oh i see what was wrong, when i first tried it i didn't have the "This tweet is example" at the front so it did work originally.

Comment: @PythonUser your solution doesn't work, strip will delete any character in the beginning or end of the word that matches "any" character in the word we put in the strip function

Comment: unnecessary comment as pylang already pointed that out and I explained what I originally did

Comment: Sometimes it takes patience to find the source of truth.  I encourage you to continue.  Find a new  way solve it.  Good luck.

Comment: I already knew how to solve it with the string added at the start; you could do what you did, but I didn't because I didn't see that it had the string at the start otherwise I would have put that.

Answer (score 0):

You may use re module:

```
import re

a = 'this tweet is example #key1_key2_key3 sdasd #key1_key2_key3'

def get_all_hashtags(text):
    hash_pattern = re.compile('\#[\w\_]+',re.IGNORECASE)
    return re.findall(hash_pattern,text)

def clean_hashtags(hashtag, return_list=False):
    # return_list just in case you want a list
    if return_list:
        return re.split('\_',hashtag.replace('#',''))
    else:
        return ' '.join(re.split('[\_]+',hashtag.replace('#','')))

print([clean_hashtags(h,True) for h in get_all_hashtags(a)])
print([clean_hashtags(h) for h in get_all_hashtags(a)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there will be only # and _ as punctuation:

```
import re

tweet = "this tweet is example #key1_key2_key3"
new_tweet = " ".join(word.strip() for word in re.split('#|_', tweet))
print (new_tweet)

Out: 'this tweet is example key1 key2 key3'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use re module:

```
a = re.sub('([#])|([^a-zA-Z])',' ',a )
```